# Mobile syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, mobile-web

I have just noticed that the mobile version does not highlight syntax.

It would be nice to have it. Of course, it is possible, as others have mentioned before when switching to desktop view, but who wants to do that?

Not that it's really important, but it's a nice readability issue that I feel needs be addressed.

Comment: I agree. Nowadays, smartphones seem to be fast enough to handle the extra eyecandy. (Which I assume is the reason it wasn't added when the mobile site was developed)

Comment: @Cerbrus It's almost like developers need 4 sites now :) Fast PC, Slow PC, Fast Phone, Slow Phone.

Comment: @Cruncher, don't forget Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Basilevs this is stackoverflow. Almost all self-respecting programmers would have downloaded something better by now